# Angular Js - ng-grid group sorting not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, ng-grid

I am using ng-grid to load job details, from which I have grouped the grid by using booking id(number column). grouping on booking level columns doesn't work. If I appended a string on the booking id column or using different column for grouping which is a string datatype, the sorting works fine.

Sorting doesn't works when I group the grid with a column which is number datatype. What do I have to do for this to work?

Comment: booking level means, booking is a master and each booking has one or more jobs

Comment: do you have an example plunker/jsfiddle handy by any chance?

Comment: Since you didn't add any plunker. Can you check on one of my answer for other question, which is also some what same kind of this scenario http://stackoverflow.com/a/29081740/2451726. Hope it may help you.

Comment: Yes, you are right, ng-grid sort function has some flaws when handling numbers valued as 0, so I fixed it using my custom sort function in my controller