# AngularJS: ng-grid does not work when using 'sortFn' and 'groups'

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I wonder if it is possible to customize the sorting and grouping to use the same column.
I made an example in Plunker where the 'groups' option is commented out. When this line is uncommented the grid does not display any records.

```
$scope.myData = [{complex:{name: "Felipe",  order: 3}},
                 {complex:{name: "Luciano", order: 1}},
                 {complex:{name: "Lucílio", order: 2}},
                 {complex:{name: "Joacás",  order: 4}}];

$scope.gridOptions = { 
  data: 'myData',
  groups: ['complex.name'], // does not work when uncommented...
  groupsCollapsedByDefault: false,
  columnDefs: [{
    field: 'complex',
    cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text>{{COL_FIELD.name}}</span></div>',
    displayName: 'Name',
    sortFn: funcOrder}]
};

var funcOrder = function sort(a, b) {
if (a.order < b.order) {
    return -1;
} else if (a.order > b.order) {
    return 1;
}
else {
    return 0;
}
```

Link Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/krlAsVr7NM30fFljyaQH

Thank U.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too faced a same kind of issue in my application and i have been solved by moving the `columnDefs` definition to the `$scope` and used in the `gridOptions`.

```
$scope.columnDefinitions = [{
    field: 'complex',
    cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text>{{COL_FIELD.name}}</span></div>',
    displayName: 'Name',
    sortFn: funcOrder
}, {
    field: 'complex',
    cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text>{{COL_FIELD.order}}</span></div>',
    displayName: 'Order'
}];

$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    groups: ['complex.name'], // Working when uncomment
    groupsCollapsedByDefault: false,
    enableSorting: true,
    columnDefs: 'columnDefinitions'
};
```

> **UPDATE 1 : [Mar 17' 2015]**

Modified the `columnDefs`'s `field` property from `complex` to `complex.name` and in the `cellTemplate` `{{COL_FIELD.name}}` to `{{COL_FIELD}}`

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    groups: ['complex.name'],
    groupsCollapsedByDefault: false,
    enableSorting: true,
    columnDefs: [{
        field: 'complex.name',
        cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text>{{COL_FIELD}}</span></div>',
        displayName: 'Name',
        sortFn: funcOrder
    }, {
        field: 'complex.order',
        cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text>{{COL_FIELD}}</span></div>',
        displayName: 'Order'
    }]
};
```

> **UPDATE 2 : [Mar 17' 2015]**

I can't able to do by using `sortFn`, instead of that i have added the `sortInfo`, `useExternalSorting` and created my customized sortData function to achieve this.

By default, i have set the **Name** as the sorting field with `asc` order. So it sorted the **Name** as well as the **Order** in `asc`. Screen shot as below:

[image: ng-grid asecnding]

When user manually set the descending order, the **Name** and **Order** fields are in `desc` order. Screen shot as below:

[image]

Can you please check the updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/itF5CdHoptP6Nij36J8T

> **UPDATE 3: [MAR 18' 2014]**

I added your question as well as my code.

> 1 ) When the controller is started, should be originator for all grouping columns.
>
> 2 ) When the user clicks on another column, the sort need to keep the grouping ( ASC ) and the column he clicked ( ASC or DESC ).

So i sorted by requested field and one more time sorted by the **grouping field** with `asc` order to retain the Grouping column wont change for any field sort.

```
angular.forEach(fields, function(item, i) {
    filterData = orderBy(filterData, [fields[i]], directions[i] == 'desc' ? true : false);
    filterData = orderBy(filterData, ['complex.name'], false);            
});
```

[New Plunker for revised code](http://plnkr.co/edit/sSNMK9UAIJyCuEzpY73C)

Hope this is what you expected.

Comment: The goal is to show the grouped names and sort by the field "order". In this case the ordering is not working.

Comment: Answer updated, now sorting is always depending on the `order` field.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you very much. But I have another question. I wanted to keep, by default, all grouping columns as ascending order in all sort of situations:

1 ) When the controller is started, should be originator for all grouping columns.

2 ) When the user clicks on another column, the sort need to keep the grouping ( ASC ) and the column he clicked ( ASC or DESC ).

The purpose of this question is not to lose the ordering of groups.

Does it have to do this ?

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/zKuQD2icA2pS2q9drhs3?p=preview

Comment: Instead of sortFn: myFunc for a custom sort function, try using sortingAlgorithm: myFunc

Comment: Arulkumar, You could take one more question?

Using his last Plunker , how do I display in the Last Name column , their own values ​​, and at the time of ordering, use the Order column to sort of reference.

Currently, the Last Name column is being sorted by their values ​​(A, B , C, D...). I wish she was ordered by the values ​​of column Order (1, 2, 3, ...)

Comment: Do you mean, the `LastName` column is always order by the `orderLastName` value? If so already sort by `Order` is the same function  right!

Comment: In this case are right, but if the Order column ( orderLastName ) were invisible ( visible: false) ?